# Stuck on Learn Ruby The Hard Way #46 rake aborted

Tags: ruby, rake, learn-ruby-the-hard-way

I made the project skeleton as described in [Learn Ruby The Hard Way #43](http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex46.html) and created the structure stated.

The problem occurs when I run `rake test` and the prompt spouts out the following:

```
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby -I"lib:tests"  "/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "tests/test_NAME.rb" 
/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit (LoadError)
    from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /mnt/30309D67309D34B6/Web Development/Tutorials/Ruby/projects/skeleton/tests/test_NAME.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:15:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:tests"  "/home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "tests/test_NAME.rb" ]

Tasks: TOP => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Can anybody tell me why the rake test gets aborted and how to possibly fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: `gem install test-unit`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Anthony! You are golden! 
Just needed to install the `test-unit` gem with `gem install test-unit`

Comment: Is it gold in here, or is it just me? :)